# GetUserStatsForGame Json [Steam, CS:GO]

Tags: json, decode, steam

How can I decode the "value" in this json?

```
{
"playerstats": {
    "steamID": "76561198054387800",
    "gameName": "ValveTestApp260",
    "stats": [
        {
            "name": "total_kills",
            "value": 19229
        },
```

Here the full json:
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=B85FE65EC6076829BEB5080BFADC8B50&steamid=76561198054387800

I already tried this:

```
$str = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=".$steamauth['apikey']."&steamids=".$_SESSION['steamid']);
$json = json_decode($str, true);
$totalkills = $json['playerstats']['stats'][0]['total_kills']['value'];
echo $totalkills . PHP_EOL;
```

Please help me :/

Comment: Confusingly, `$json['playerstats']['stats'][0]` is an array with two keys called `name` and `value`. The value you want is in `$json['playerstats']['stats'][0]['value']`. Please copy the relevant parts of the JSON file into your question — as it stands, this question is of little use to anyone and will probably be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for the answer im really sorry for this inaccurate question. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will work.

```
$totalkills = $json['playerstats']['stats'][0]['value'];
echo $totalkills . PHP_EOL;
```

But as stats is an array, it's kinda unsafe to assume totalkills always will be in position 0 of the array. It's safer to loop through the array and find the value your are looking for.

```
foreach ($json['playerstats']['stats'] as $i) {
    if ($i['name'] == "total_kills") {
        echo $i['name'] . " :" . $i['value'];
    }
}
```